# Windows Azure SDK 2.0 and old runtime assemblies in GAC

Tags: azure, sdk, gac

I've installed Windows Azure SDK 2.0 and started to migrate my project. After installation of 2.0 I uninstalled all items for 2012-10 (the previous version) from Programs and Features (my environment is Win8 Pro + VS2012 SP2).

I expected when I open project with references to the old version of Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime that I will see broken references, so I would be easily  able to find them and replace with the latest version. However the old versions of Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime remained in GAC (1.7 and 1.8) so the projects still compile. Trying to uninstall old assemblies from GAC I'm getting Access Denied.

I believe I would be able to remove them somehow but my question is - did they remain there intentionally? Do I need these old versions for something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no projects that rely on the older versions, feel free to remove. Have you tried uninstalling the old SDKs. If you have, and the old assemblies still remain then:

You should be able to remove the old version by doing the following:

1. Open an elevated cmd prompt (run as administrator)
2. gacutil.exe -u microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll

Comment: As I wrote, I uninstalled everything related to previous version of Azure I found in "Programs and Features". However, the assemblies 1.7 and 1.8 were left in GAC. Trying to uninstall them from GAC in command line it reports _Unable to uninstall: assembly is required by one or more applications_. As I can't find any related installer I guess I can clear the registry as described in [KB8873195](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/873195/en-us) and then delete them from GAC. Just wondering why they were not uninstalled with previous SDKs?

Comment: They probably weren't removed by the install for the same reason you can't uninstall them, they're being used by one or more applications. The link you found is probably the right way to go on this one. Did running from the elevated prompt get around "Access Denied"?

Comment: Actually the assemblies were not being used by another application. They have been installed by installer (Azure SDK 1.7, resp. 1.8), which increased they reference count and during uninstall the reference counter wasn't decreased. Perhaps the order of installation (the newer version had been installed first and then the previous version has been removed) or some bug in the installer.. 'Access denied' came from explorer, so using cmd as Admin helped. My problem was not how to remove the assembly but if it is safe (or if there is some reason for new SDK to keep it). Anyway, I removed it. Thanks